# How to integrate $\int_0^\infty e^{-ty^2} \sin t dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

My book suggests that I do some sort of limiting

$\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_0^A e^{-ty^2} \sin t d t$

But I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: Hint: $\sin t=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$ will take you to an antiderivative.

Comment: Hmmm...that trick leaves us, I think, with one divergent improper integral.

Comment: Got it, thanks guys. It's $\frac{1}{y^4+1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the initial integral.
You can integrate it by parts.
$$\int_0^A e^{-ty^2} \sin t d t=-\int_0^A e^{-ty^2}  d \cos(t)=-\left(e^{-ty^2}\cos(t)\bigg|_0^A  -(-y^2)\int_0^A \cos(t)e^{-ty^2}  dt \right)$$
$$\int_0^A e^{-ty^2} \sin t d t=-e^{-ty^2}\cos(t)\bigg|_0^A  -y^2\int_0^A e^{-ty^2}  d\sin(t)=-e^{-ty^2}\cos(t)\bigg|_0^A -y^2\left(e^{-ty^2}\sin(t)\bigg|_0^A  -(-y^2)\int_0^A \sin(t)e^{-ty^2}  dt \right) $$
$$\int_0^A e^{-ty^2} \sin t dt=1-e^{-Ay^2}(\cos(A)+y^2\sin(A))-y^4\int_0^A e^{-ty^2} \sin t dt$$
$$(1+y^4)\int_0^A e^{-ty^2} \sin t dt=1-e^{-Ay^2}(\cos(A)+y^2\sin(A))$$
$$\int_0^A e^{-ty^2} \sin t dt=\frac{1-e^{-Ay^2}(\cos(A)+y^2\sin(A))}{(1+y^4)}$$
And finally takong the limit one can obtain the answer:
$$\lim_{A \to \infty} \int_0^A e^{-ty^2} \sin t d t=\frac{\lim_{A \to \infty} (1-e^{-Ay^2}(\cos(A)+y^2\sin(A))) }{1+y^4}=\frac{1}{1+y^4}$$

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way is to recognize that

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-b t} = \frac{1}{b}$$

when $\Re{b} \gt 0$.  Then write

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-t y^2} \, \sin{t} = \Im{\left [ \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-(y^2 - i) t} \right]} = \Im{\left[\frac{1}{y^2-i}\right]} = \frac{1}{y^4+1}$$

Comment: You need $\mbox{Re}\;b>0$.

Comment: @julien: thanks.

Comment: @RonGordon Nicely done! :)

Comment: I have a query ,,, why among all people only you write $\int dx f(x)$ instead of $\int f(x) dx$ ??

Comment: @experimentX: I assume you missed the hijinx here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387572/notation-why-write-the-differential-first/387577#comment830158_387577

Comment: all right thanks for explanation (+1)

Answer (score 1):

you can use Euler formula $e^{i\pi}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess there some other interesting ways to solve the problem.
One more try.
You can look at that integral as the Laplace transform:
$$F(s) =\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) \,dt$$
obtained for $s=y^2$.

 So you have $f(t)=\sin(t), \ s=y^2$. It is well [known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) that the Laplace transform of $ \sin(\omega t)$ is $ { \omega \over s^2 + \omega^2  } $ . So just set $\omega=1$ and one will obtain:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ty^2} \sin t dt=\frac{1}{y^4+1}$$

Comment: Well, all of these answers are nifty.