# Meaning of the following integal

Tags: integration, notation

What does
$\int d^3 x $
mean?

I found this in a lecture on quantum field theory, and it was not explained.

Comment: $d^3x$ a short hand for $dx_1 dx_2 dx_3$, the volume element of a 3 dimension integral.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of $\int\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}^4x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426263/meaning-of-int-mathop-mathrmd4x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In physics notation, it means a triple integral over the whole 3-dimensional space. An equation like:
$$
\int d^3x\,f(x)
$$

actually means:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz. 
$$

For example, a 3-dimensional Fourier transform can be written as:

$$
\tilde{f}(p) = \int d^3x\,f(x)\,e^{-ip\cdot x},
$$

which means:
$$
\tilde{f}(p_1, p_2,p_3) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y,z)\,e^{-ip_1x-ip_2y-ip_3z}\,dx\,dy\,dz.
$$

It is a little unclear at first, but as you can see, it shortens the formulas a lot.