# Solve Double Integral, likely using Fubini's Theorem

Tags: calculus

[image: Question]

The second form throws me, that the dy appears before the second integral. I have unfortunately little skill for Calculus, and I can't seem to find a similar question online to take example from. All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The righthand expression means the same as $$\int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{y}}^1\frac1{2+x^3}dxdy\;,$$ a form that may be more familiar to you.

Comment: Invaluable! Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387572/notation-why-write-the-differential-first

Comment: @anorton: Done.

Answer (score 3):

The righthand expression means the same as $$\int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{y}}^1\frac1{2+x^3}dxdy\;,$$ a form that may be more familiar to you.

Answer (score 0):

A double integral is a like a summation over two variables.
In your example, the first sum is taken over a variable x,
with y fixed.  Let's call the resulting sum a function of y -- g(y).
The 2nd sum is over a variable y, with the summands or terms equal
to different values of g(y).